# Rails 5: increment value to existing array and keep old values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to increment new values to an array but the old values get deleted. As you can see in the following, I had one image there and now its `NULL`, but the new image is there.

```
SQL (1.5ms)  UPDATE "attachments" SET "media_files" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "attachments"."id" = $3  [["media_files", "{NULL,image4.jpg}"], ["updated_at", "2018-10-25 09:12:05.564281"], ["id", 11]]
```

I'm using the `carrierwave gem` and this is the method I have inside the controller in order to keep the existing values and increment the new ones:

```
def create
  files = @attachment.media_files # copy the old images
  files += params[:item][:media_files] # add new file to the files
  @attachment.assign_attributes(:media_files => files) # assign back
  if @attachment.save
    flash[:notice] = "Media files where successfully uploaded"
    redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Failed to upload media files"
    redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
  end
end
```

And the form is:

```
<%= form_for @item, url: create_image_path(@attachment), method: :post , :html => {:id => "form"} do |f| %>

<%= f.file_field :media_files, multiple: true %>
<%= f.submit 'Add' %>
<% end %>
```

Models associations:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attachments, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, allow_destroy: true
end

class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  mount_uploaders :media_files, AttachmentUploader
  validates_presence_of :media_files
end
```

The schema for the two models:

```
create_table "attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "item_id"
  t.integer "account_id"
  t.string "media_files", default: [], array: true
  t.string "content_type"
  t.boolean "success"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "title"
  t.string "description"
  t.integer "category_id"
  t.integer "account_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

The route for the create method:

```
post "item/:id/uploads/media_files/:id"=> "attachments#create", :as => :create_image
```

Any idea what I might be missing here?

Comment: Can you show your associations and schema about item and attachments?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Gabbar, I just added the info to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with your own code the modification need to done is: -

```
def create
  exitsting_files = @attachment.media_files # copy the old images
  new_file = params[:item][:media_files] # new file to the files
  new_attachment = Aattachment.new(:media_files => new_file, id: @item.id) #New attachment submitted by form
  if new_attachment.save
    #push back your exitsting_files along with new one
    @attachment.media_files.push(exitsting_files)
    @attachment.save
    flash[:notice] = "Media files where successfully uploaded"
    redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Failed to upload media files"
    redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
  end
end
```

However this should be done with `nested_atrributes_for` concept

```
<%= form_for @item, url: create_image_path(@attachment), method: :post , :html => {:id => "form"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for : attachments do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.file_field :media_files, multiple: true %>
  <%end%>
  <%= f.submit 'Add' %>
<% end %>
```

And so on... you can get lots of [example for nested form](http://www.parsonsmatt.org/2015/01/10/rails_forms.html)

Comment: I'm getting an error `undefined method `new' for #<Attachment:0x007fab867b9038>` at this line: `new_attachment = @attachment.new(:media_files => new_files) #New attachment submitted by form`

Comment: btw the route of the form is the create method. I added the route to my question.

Comment: @Dev am going with your flow so idea is to create new attachment and after that push back your  existing attachments by pushing back means it should add copied  filed + new one that is just created. and finally save it . that's it , and for that error i have modified answer , it should be `Aattachment.new(...fields: value)`

Comment: Unfortunately its not working @Gabber... Its going to the `else` flash message "Failed to upload media files". I tried putting an `save!` in order to see whats wrong but it just bypasses it and goes straight to the message.

Comment: I'm using the form I have and not nested_form... just copied the create code

Comment: @Dev That's fine AS i observe Attachment model have some belong_to association which means those field required at the time of creation of attachment, so please pass all field which are required possibly pass ietme_id, account_id .`Aattachment.new(:media_files => new_file, id: @item.id, account_id: id_of_account)`

Comment: @Gabber, ok I go it to pass that line by adding what was necessary. But now I'm getting an error `undefined method pus' for #<Attachment:0x007fb9f2c2af20>` on this line `@attachment.push(exitsting_files)`

Comment: @Dev sorry my bad it should be `@attachment.media_files.push(exitsting_files)`

Comment: Its ok @Gabber, you have been so much help thus far. Thanks! I kind of figured that and changed it, but now I'm getting an error `undefined method identifier' for #<Array:0x007fb9fb29bbe0>` on tis line: `@attachment.save!` We're so close.

Comment: @Dev Hi, dev am sorry about that, not able to figure out what cause this error but i can given you some implementation example hopefully that will help you http://bobintornado.github.io/rails/2015/12/29/Multiple-Images-Uploading-With-CarrierWave-and-PostgreSQL-Array.html

Comment: @Dev Anyway feel free to accept/upvote answer if it's helpful for you :)

Comment: @Dev did you get any help by the link i have mentioned in previous comment?

Comment: I already implemented this previously which had the same exact behavior. The old files where getting deleted but the new ones were created. That led me to to this approach which didn't work as well. So i'm kind of stuck right know. I would  appreciate any other help you can give me or another way to implement this @Gabbar!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182494/discussion-between-gabbar-and-dev).

Comment: Thanks @Gabbar ... I've add the `cocoon gem` and it works just fine. It's awesome!

Comment: @Dev Glad to know that :)